# Visual C#: copy text file into output directory in custom charset

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio, I created an empty file (supposed to be a log file) and marked it as "Copy to output directory". It contains 3 bytes (BOM UTF-8).

If I manually delete all contents in external editor, it is copied as is, 0 bytes. However if I add one character in Visual Studio editor, it is copied as 4 bytes file - the BOM is back.

I don't like that. Is there a way how to tell Visual Studio not to add BOM?

Comment: Simple solution: Use a different editor to create the file.

Comment: I do. But when I edit it in Visual studio, it is so clever to add it :-( It is no big deal, but to disable this "feature" would be nice.